# regular expression disallow in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I want to select all literal letter **s** but not literal word **\s**

```
(?<!\\)s
```

works in c# but I'm not able to adjust it to work with javascript. how do I disallow literal **\s** in javascript matching all literal **s**?

for example int the expression: test\ss should match te`s`t\s`s`

**Edit:**
as Mitch says I  want to catch all literal s that are not after a literal \

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: So, you want to catch all literal **s** that are not after a literal \ ?

Comment: @hwnd could you please show me how?

Comment: Are you replacing or matching?

Comment: I'm replacing s with ş but I don't want /s to be replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [**DIY**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#diy) Boundaries ...

```
var r = 'test\\ss'.replace(/(^|[^\\])s/gi, '$1ş');
console.log(r); //=> 'teşt\sş'
```

Or use a workaround:

```
var r = 'test\\ss'.replace(/(\\)?s/gi, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $0 : 'ş'; });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment in your question, try this then

```
/(?:\B|\s)s/g
```

Try this in your browsers console to confirm it works

```
re = /(?:\B|\s)s/g;
str = 'test\\ss';
res = str.match(re)
console.log(str.replace(re, '0'));
```

`res` will have 2 results in it